# marker-end not getting displayed

Tags: html, css, svg, d3.js

I have a following html:

```
<div id="divVis2" class="divVis">
    <svg width="1540" height="345">
        <defs>
            <marker id="normal" viewBox="0 -5 10 10" refX="15" refY="-1.5" markerWidth="6" markerHeight="6" orient="auto">
                <path d="M0,-5L10,0L0,5"></path>
            </marker>
            <marker id="anomaly" viewBox="0 -5 10 10" refX="15" refY="-1.5" markerWidth="6" markerHeight="6" orient="auto">
                <path d="M0,-5L10,0L0,5"></path>
            </marker>
        </defs>
        <g>
            <path class="anomaly" marker-end="url(#anomaly)" d="M908.3739002256449,176.0182689704716L661.9527686239043,249.64760217208658"></path>
            <path class="normal" marker-end="url(#normal)" d="M660.4045373167714,246.37428873149702L879.5700343222044,98.59473202412175"></path>
            <path class="normal" marker-end="url(#normal)" d="M878.0019325543491,95.25420149730667L631.216835426003,167.4248240636326"></path>
        </g>
        <g>
            <g transform="translate(889.5195255254339,91.88595979689137)">
                <circle class="normal" r="12"></circle>
                <text x="0" y="4" class="normal">133</text>
            </g>
            <g transform="translate(619.6992424549181,170.7930657640479)">
                <circle class="normal" r="12"></circle>
                <text x="0" y="4" class="normal">134</text>
            </g>
            <g transform="translate(650.4550461135419,253.0830609587274)">
                <circle class="anomaly" r="12"></circle>
                <text x="0" y="4" class="normal">137</text>
            </g>
            <g transform="translate(919.8716227360072,172.5828101838308)">
                <circle class="normal" r="12"></circle>
                <text x="0" y="4" class="normal">136_1</text>
            </g>
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Its corresponding css is:

```
#divVis2 path {
    fill: none;
    /* stroke: #666; */
    stroke-width: 0.5px;
}

#divVis2 path.normal {
    stroke: #808080;
}

#divVis2 path.anomaly {
    stroke: red;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

/* for the marker */
#divVis2 #normal {
    fill: black;
    stroke-width: 0.5px;
}

#divVis2 #anomaly {
    fill: red;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

#divVis2 circle.normal  {
    fill: #ccc;
    stroke: #ffffff;
    stroke-width: 0.5px;
}


#divVis2 circle.anomaly {
    fill: #ff0000;
    stroke: #ffffff;
    stroke-width: 0.5px;
}


#divVis2 text.normal {
    font: 7px sans-serif;
    pointer-events: none;
    fill: black;
    text-anchor:middle;

}

#divVis2 text.label  {
    font: 9px sans-serif;
    pointer-events: none;
    fill: blue;
    text-anchor:middle;

}
```

The corresponding output in browser is:
[image]

Why are the arrows not getting displayed at the end of each path? I am unable to find out the problem in css selectors.

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/onh7t53o/

Comment: would you be able to put together a JSFiddle ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#divVis2 path {
    fill: none;
    /* stroke: #666; */
    stroke-width: 0.5px;
}
```

has a higher specificity for the markers than

```
 #divVis2 #normal {
    fill: black;
    stroke-width: 0.5px;
}
```

so the marker paths are fill="none" and the stroke-width is so thin because the markers are small that you can't see it.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem in an angular app that was using a `<base>` tag. In the context of a rich web app like one built on Angular, where you need to set the `<base>` tag to make HTML5-style navigation work, it can get messy to try to fix that in a permanent way.

In my case, the app I was working on was showing a [SVG-based interactive diagram builder](http://bpmn.io) that would change the app url as I selected elements therein.

What I did was to add a global event handler that would fix all `url(#...)` inline styles in any `<path>` element found in the page:

```coffee
$rootScope.$on 'fixSVGReference', ->
    $('path').each ->
        $path = $ this
        if (style = $path.attr 'style')?
            $path.attr 'style', style.replace /url\([^)#]*#/g, "url(#{location.href}\#"
```

Then trigger this handler in key places, like when the app state changes (I'm using [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router))

```coffee
$rootScope.$on '$stateChangeSuccess', ->
    $timeout (-> $rootScope.$emit 'fixSVGReference'), 5
```

As well as anywhere where I know there'd be new/updated paths like these. Here, the `$timeout` thing is to account for the fact that the DOM nodes really are changed asynchronously sometime after the `$stateChangeSuccess` event is triggered.

Comment: This is more of a comment. Can you upgrade it to an answer or if the questions are duplicates, flag as duplicate?